# Passing delegate to CompiledQuery.Compile method

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

While trying to pass delegate `System.Func<T,TResult>` to `CompiledQuery.Compile` method, I am getting the following error

"**Error    1   The type arguments for method 'System.Data.Linq.CompiledQuery.Compile(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly**."

```
public static void CompiledLINQQuery()
{
    Northwind_LINQtoSQLDataContext objData = new Northwind_LINQtoSQLDataContext();
    Func<Northwind_LINQtoSQLDataContext, IQueryable<Customer>> LINQHolder = GetPreCompiledQuery;

    LINQHolder = CompiledQuery.Compile(LINQHolder); //This is where the error comes up           
    var Results = LINQHolder.Invoke(objData);   
}

private static IQueryable<Customer> GetPreCompiledQuery(Northwind_LINQtoSQLDataContext objD)
{
    return from cust in objD.Customers where cust.Country == "Germany" select cust;
}
```

at the same time, if I pass the LINQ directly to the `CompiledQuery.Compile` method, then it works without any errors.

```
LINQHolder = CompiledQuery.Compile((Northwind_LINQtoSQLDataContext objD) => from cust in objD.Customers where cust.Country == "Germany" select cust);
```

I dont understand why I am not able to pass a delegate instead of the LINQ query expression.

Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

[CompiledQuery.Compile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.compiledquery.compile.aspx)() is only defined on Expression<Func<>>, but not on Func<>

Does your code compile if you re-write the statement as

```
var LINQHolder = GetPreCompiledQuery;
var CompiledLINQHolder = CompiledQuery.Compile(LINQHolder);
```

?

Comment: That won't compile on the first line, apart from anything else - the initialization expression of an implicitly typed local variable can't be a method group.

Answer (score 1):

You're not able to pass a delegate because the method signature specifies an expression tree, not a delegate - it's as simple as that. They are two very different sets of types.

What they have in common - and the reason your final piece of code will compile - is that the compiler can convert a *lambda expression* into either a delegate or an expression tree. Now that's not how you're creating the delegate in the first case - you're actually using a method group conversion. That's never going to create an expression tree.

If you want to specify your query in a separate method, it will have to be something like this:

```
private static Expression<Func<Northwind_LINQtoSQLDataContext,
                               IQueryable<Customer>>
    GetPreCompiledQuery()
{
    return db => from cust in db.Customers 
                 where cust.Country == "Germany"
                 select cust;
}
```

By the way, it's worth being aware that for simple queries, query expressions are often more cumbersome than using the extension methods. For example, the above is equivalent to:

```
private static Expression<Func<Northwind_LINQtoSQLDataContext,
                               IQueryable<Customer>>
    GetPreCompiledQuery()
{
    return db => db.Customers.Where(cust => cust.Country == "Germany");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I supplied the following to the LINQHolder definition as well as to the return type of GetPreCompiled method. `**"Expression<Func<Northwind_LINQtoSQLDataContext, IQueryable<Customer>>> LINQHolder = GetPreCompiledQuery;"**` but now i am getting error like 
"**Cannot convert method group 'GetPreCompiledQuery' to non-delegate type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Practical_LINQToSQL.LINQtoSQLDemo.Northwind_LINQtoSQLDataContext,System.Linq.IQueryable<Practical_LINQToSQL.LINQtoSQLDemo.Customer>>>'. Did you intend to invoke the method?**"